# Any way to avoid a filesort when order by is different to where clause?

Tags: mysql

I have an incredibly simple query (table type InnoDb) and `EXPLAIN` says that MySQL must do an extra pass to find out how to retrieve the rows in sorted order.

```
SELECT * FROM `comments` 
WHERE (commentable_id = 1976) 
ORDER BY created_at desc LIMIT 0, 5
```

exact explain output:

```
table   select_type     type    extra                          possible_keys   key             key length   ref     rows
comments   simple      ref   using where; using filesort    common_lookups  common_lookups  5   const   89
```

commentable_id is indexed. Comments has nothing trick in it, just a content field.

The manual suggests that if the order by is different to the where, there is no way filesort can be avoided.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html

I also tried order by id as well as it's equivalent but makes no difference, even if I add id as an index (which I understand is not required as id is indexed implicitly in MySQL).

thanks in advance for any ideas!

To Mark -- here's SHOW CREATE TABLE

```
CREATE TABLE `comments` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `user_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `commentable_type` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `commentable_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `content` text,
  `created_at` datetime default NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime default NULL,
  `hidden` tinyint(1) default '0',
  `public` tinyint(1) default '1',
  `access_point` int(11) default '0',
  `item_id` int(11) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `created_at` (`created_at`),
  KEY `common_lookups` (`commentable_id`,`commentable_type`,`hidden`,`created_at`,`public`),
  KEY `index_comments_on_item_id` (`item_id`),
  KEY `index_comments_on_item_id_and_created_at` (`item_id`,`created_at`),
  KEY `index_comments_on_user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=31803 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: +1 for using Explain first, although I can't honestly say I fully understand how to decipher an Explain statement.  Will have to figure that out one of these days. :)

Comment: Can you also post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE comments`?

Comment: @Robert Harvey: Try Baron Schwartz' excellent presentation: http://www.percona.com/files/presentations/EXPLAIN_demystified.pdf

Comment: Since the query answers your requirements, have you measured to establish how much the sort actually costs?  It is unlikely to be a significant problem, even if a single commentable_id has several hundred comments associated with it.

Comment: Thanks guys. Yes I'd read various articles about how filesort is badly named and is memory-based by default. What I'm hearing is that there's no obvious query- or index-level issues with my approach so I'll investigate this further if, in production, this becomes a performance bottleneck in some way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the MySQL term *filesort* doesn't necessarily mean it writes to the disk.  It just means it's going to sort without using an index.  If the result set is small enough, MySQL will sort it in memory, which is orders of magnitude faster than disk I/O.

You can increase the amount of memory MySQL allocates for in-memory filesorts using the [`sort_buffer_size`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sort_buffer_size) server variable.  In MySQL 5.1, the default sort buffer size is 2MB, and the maximum you can allocate is 4GB.

---

**update:** Regarding Jonathan Leffler's comment about measuring how long the sorting takes, you can learn how to use [`SHOW PROFILE FOR QUERY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-profiles.html) which will give you the breakdown of how long each phase of query execution takes.

Comment: Thanks Bill. I'll keep sort_buffer_size in mind definitely as the jump from in-memory to disk surely will have a big hit and I need to do some graded load testing to see where this elbows...

Comment: show profile and set profiling=1 are deprecated in current versions.

Comment: @Ross, good point, the new way to do this is with PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA. But to be fair, SHOW PROFILE is deprecated in MySQL 5.6.7 and later. MySQL 5.5 is still a current version today.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a combined index on (commentable_id, created_at).